# Wireless Network Unclaimed on G750JM using ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, broadcom

I read a few similar questions but none have answered this problem in a way that works. The answer generally seems that it is a system error but most of the questions are a few months old and I still have hope for an answer.
I have a `Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)`.

The adapter is on in my `Additional Adapters` but that's it. When I use the command `sudo lshw -C network` it provides

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Limited
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:eda00000-eda07fff memory:ed800000-ed9fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 40:16:7e:0e:87:0f
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.0.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:33 memory:edb00000-edb3ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
```

How do I claim the network?

I tried `sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-jaunty` as described in a few answers but I got

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package linux-backports-modules-jaunty
```

Comment: What happens when you enable the driver in `Additional Drivers`?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -al /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto*`?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 168 Jan  7 16:48 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  80 Feb 18  2016 /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist

Comment: and nothing happens in 'Additional Drivers' . After I restart my computer, nothing at all changes

Comment: But there is a driver listed there, yes? What is the output of `dkms status`?

Comment: bbswitch, 0.8, 4.4.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.248+bdcom, 4.4.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-367, 367.57, 4.4.0-57-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Is `secure boot` disabled in your BIOS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51387/discussion-between-dj-aduvanchik-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments and the chat...

To enable the bcmwl driver for your wireless card, you need to disable `Secure Boot` in your BIOS.

To fix the error `Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/'`, type this in the `terminal`...

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist ~/Documents
```